# if/elif/else statement in a while loop with python

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, syntax-error

I'm new to python so this may be a beginner question. My 'else' statement in the code below gets a syntax error for a reason beyond my mind. I've looked up the syntax for it multiple times but I cannot find the error. This is my python code:

```
siteswap = input("Enter the siteswap you want to validate here:")  
aantal_digits = len(siteswap)  
i = 0  
j = 1  
while i != aantal_digits:  
    if (int(siteswap[i])+ (i + 1)) % aantal_digits == (int(siteswap[1:aantal_digits])+ (j + 1)) % aantal_digits:  
            print("This siteswap is invalid")  
            break  
    elif i != aantal_digits:  
        del (int(siteswap[i])  
    else:  
        print ("This siteswap is valid")
        break
```

The else is highlighted and I get a "syntax error".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is

```
del (int(siteswap[i])
```

You are missing a closing parenthesis (but the parenthesis are unnecessary in the first place). Also, `del int(siteswap[i])` will not work, because you cannot delete function calls: `SyntaxError: can't delete function call`

```
del siteswap[i]
```

will delete the actual item from your array.

Comment: My eyes were open wider and wider with the vote this answer recieved. :-)

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my question so quick! I will try to remember this for the next time. Have a nice day!